# How to create two different Index can't duplicate?

Tags: indexing, duplicates, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have in `MyTable` two different fields, `FieldA` and `FieldB`.

I want to create two indexes with `AllowDuplicates` set to `No`, because there should be no records with same `FieldA` and `FieldB`.

If I create two indexes for each field, it allows me nonetheless to create records with values for example `FieldB` same value.

Is it possible to set two different indexes for two different fields? Because these fields are independent of each other or do I have to use the code solution (`validateWrite`, `insert`, `update` etc.)?

See below for an example: **I do not want this to happen**.
Two records with same `FieldB` (or vice versa /conversely).

[image: my situation]

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: If your index FieldBX is also set to AllowDuplicates=No then the data in the screenshot you made is not possible - if that was possible then try an additional DB sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to synchronize the table. Do so on the context menu of the table. You will need to delete the duplicates first!

If still a problem, take a look on the table from SQL Enterprise Manager (it is called Studio nowadays).

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen yua have a reason I have to synchronize the table, and work well. Very kind!